# Calculating and displaying intersection of cylinder and line

Tags: equation-solving, geometry

I am trying to compute and display the intersection of a line defined by two points and a cylinder centered around the $z$-axis defined by length and radius. So far I have

```
cyl = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]
line = InfiniteLine[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]
pts = Solve[{x, y, z} ∈ cyl && {x, y, z} ∈ line, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

But this returns `y -> ConditionalExpression[0, -1 <= x <= 1], z -> 
 ConditionalExpression[0, -1 <= x <= 1]` instead of a single solution. Any hint why this is the case and how to display the solution with the intersection in a nice way?

Comment: Try [`RegionIntersection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html)?

Comment: Third point under "Details" in the docs for `Cylinder[]`: "`Cylinder` represents a **filled cylinder region**..." (emphasis mine). So yes, the result you got is correct, and you indeed have a continuum of points. Use `RegionBoundary[Cylinder[(* stuff *)]]` if you only want the surface.

Comment: @J.M. ahh that makes sense, what would be the best way to just get the intersections with a hollow cylinder?

Comment: @Mark @jm just told you: use the `RegionBoundary` approach in his comment to get only the surface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the display

```
cyl = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1];
line = InfiniteLine[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}];
pts = {x, y, z} /. Solve[{x, y, z} ∈ 
    RegionIntersection[line, RegionBoundary[cyl]], {x, y, z}]

(* {{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}} *)

Graphics3D[
 {{Opacity[0.25], cyl},
  {Thick, Red, line},
  {Black, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[pts]}},
 PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a composition of [`RegionIntersection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html), [`DiscretizeRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html) and [`MeshCoordinates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCoordinates.html):

```
MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeRegion @ RegionIntersection[cyl, line]]
```

> ```
> {{-1., 0., 0.}, {1., 0., 0.}}
> ```

Or combine the three steps in a function:

```
intersection = MeshCoordinates @* DiscretizeRegion @* RegionIntersection;
intersection[cyl, line]
```

> ```
> {{-1., 0., 0.}, {1., 0., 0.}}
> ```

Alternatively, you can use a combination of [`RegionIntersection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html), [`DiscretizeRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html) and [`MeshPrimitives`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshPrimitives.html):

```
MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[cyl, line], 0]
```

> ```
> {Point[{-1., 0., 0.}], Point[{1., 0., 0.}]}
> ```